# How do I make it so the code only shifts the letters and not the space?

Tags: python, encryption

```
#get string and shift from user

string = input('Please enter a string to be ciphered: ')
shift = input('Please enter a shift amount between 0 and 25: ')

#strings are immutable so it must be converted to a list
s=list(string)

#now this will convert each character based on the shift

for i in range(0,len(s)):
    s[i]=chr(ord(s[i]) + int(shift))


print ("".join(s))
```

Comment: You should think about what will happen if the string is "zombie" and the shift is 1.

Answer (score 1):

You should call the method [str.alpha](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) to ensure that the chosen element is an alphabet before shifting

```
for i in range(0,len(s)):
    if elem.isaplha():
        s[i]=chr(ord(s[i]) + int(shift))
```

On a second though, you are doing to much work here. Why not use a comprehension expression?

```
s = ''.join(chr(ord(elem) + shift) if elem.isalpha() else elem for elem in s)
```

or if you are adventurous enough

```
s = ''.join([elem, chr(ord(elem) + shift)][elem.isalpha()] for elem in s)
```

and finally have you checked the [string.makestrans](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) along with [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) to do the conversion?

```
from string import maketrans, ascii_alpha
s = s.translate(maketrans(ascii_alpha[shift:] + string.ascii_alpha[:shift])
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is check if the current character is not one you want to skip.

```
for i in range(0,len(s)):
    #If not a space, cipher this character.
    if s[i] != ' ':
        s[i]=chr(ord(s[i]) + int(shift))
```

There is however, a possibility that one of your characters will be ciphered to a space, in which case that character would be skipped when reversing the cipher.

Also, a simple cipher like this should not be considered secure in the least.